# Change Integer value inside a for loop

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop, integer

Hey guys having trouble with what i thought would be an easy task to accomplish. I'm having trouble changing an integer variables value inside a for loop, maybe since its inside a for loop you have to do something technical?

But i have a function called `addPointsToStage();` I made it public since I'm trying to access it's integer variable through a separate function. Its inside the same class by the way.

This is how it looks:

```
public function addPointsToStage():void
    {
         var startPoint:Point = new Point((stage.stageWidth / 2) - 100, stage.stageHeight / 2);
         var xSpacing:Number = 70;
         ySpacing = 0;

         for (var i = 0; i < nPoints; i++)
         {
             trace(aPointsArray.length);
             points = new mcGainPoints();
             aPointsArray.push(points);
             stage.addChild(points);
             points.x = startPoint.x + (xSpacing * i);
             points.y = startPoint.y - (ySpacing *i);
         }

    }
```

I'm trying to change the `ySpacing =0;` i promoted it to a class member and i wanted to channge the value of this  part `points.y = startPoint.y - (ySpacing *i);`  through a hitTest Function i have, i try adding this because i thought it was that simple `ySpacing = 10;` But it didn't do anything.

There was no error, it just didn't change the value inside the for loop.

Can you see what im doing wrong here?

Comment: How do you know it didn't change in the loop ? Based on what I see here, the value will be 0.

Comment: If you want to change `ySpacing` elsewhere, REMOVE by all means `ySpacing=0` from inside of this function body. Also, for this purpose `xSpacing` should undergo the same modification, that is, make it class-wide, assign it a start value and allow changing from elsewhere by some means.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help i was WAY over thinking it. I've been learning a lot harder coding lately to where the easier things are impossible to figure out haha. Thanks so much though guys